# prettyPrint jsonNode in Play

Tags: json, playframework-2.0, jackson

Via the Play WS API I get() a Response object. As it contains JSON I call

```
response.asJson()
```

which works perfectly fine. Now I want to return this JSON in a prettyprinted version so I tried to call

```
Json.prettyPrint(response.asJson())
```

However this does not work because prettyPrint expects a JsValue, not a JsonNode. 
**So the question is how to convert a JsonNode to a JsObject?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am guessing you are using Play with Java. Instead of converting to JsValue, you could do something like:

```
JsonNode node = response.asJson();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
String pretty = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(node);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Pull request #2924](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2924) (Currently only available in master as of 2014-05-26) improves Play Framework to allow converting between JsValue and JsonNode, etc.

<del>As far as I know there still isn't a prettyPrint in the Java Json package, but this is one step closer.</del>

Pretty print and some other functions (to bring the Java in line with the Scala) added in [#2945](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/2945) (Currently only available in master as of 2014-05-28)